# Running a program inside an LXC container with a specific user

Tags: lxc, container

I want to run a program inside a container with a specific user. By default, when using lxc-attach, the user is root, but I don't want to execute the program as root.

Command I want to execute:

```
lxc-attach -n container -- python3 some_program.py
```

When attached to the container, I want the user to be uid=1000 not uid=0 (root)

I know it's possible with lxc-execute, with lxc.init_uid and lxc.init_gid [[src: LXC.CONTAINER.CONF(5)]](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/lxc.container.conf.5.html), but with lxc-execute I don't have network connection (because the container is not running?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `su` to change the user:

```
$ sudo lxc-attach -n test -- su ubuntu -c 'whoami'
ubuntu
```

Your command would look like this (if you don't know the username):

```
lxc-attach -n container -- 'su $(getent passwd 1000| cut -f1 -d:) -c "python3 some_program.py"'
```